# How to access the recipients list of an unsent Outlook message from Applescript

Tags: outlook, applescript

I'm trying to put together an Applescript (MacOS 10.15.6) that will read the recipients of a newly-composed but unsent message in Outlook (v16.40). So, to clarify, I'd:

1. Start a new message in Outlook
2. Add some recipients to the To and Cc fields
3. Run the Applescript and have access to the recipient information *before* the message is sent.

I've hit a stumbling block straight away: I can't seem to access the new message.

```
tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
  set newMessage to get (outgoing message)
  set reciplist to every recipient of newMessage
end tell
```

gives the syntax error

> Can’t get every recipient of outgoing message.

I can't find any examples of looking at unsent and unsaved messages - is such a thing possible?

Comment: I don't have MS Outlook. However, `list` is a reserved word - use another variable name instead. For example `set recipientsList to recipients of newMessage` Also note, your example code has two `to`'s, you only need one.

Comment: good point - I've changed the variable name above. `to recipient` is listed in the AppleScript dictionary, but it looks awkward, so I've changed it to a clearer example.